# React-native build error Android - java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native

I have setup the react native project as mentioned in react-native documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html). On building using the command `react-native run-android`, I am getting the following error.

> Starting JS server... Building and installing the app on the device
>   (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/var/www/html/react-native/NewProject/android/app/build.gradle' line:
>     1
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version
>   >     52.0
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

Development Environment

- Linux
- Android SDK
- java version is `java version "1.8.0_121"`

Android SDK
[image: android sdk]

Android SDK Build Tools installed 23.0.1, 23.0.2

Could you please someone help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At last figured out the problem

check `$JAVA_HOME`

Need JDK 1.8 to work

Install Java JDK 1.8 and change the `JAVA_HOME`

edit `~/.bashrc` and add JDK 1.8 path as `JAVA_HOME`

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/`

and `source ~/.bashrc`
close the current terminal window/tab and run

`react-native run-android`

in new tab (ensure `$JAVA_HOME` set to jdk 1.8 before this)

Comment: Incase anyone else struggles with this, I had to go download jdk1.8 from Oracle on Mac. Android Studio was using 1.7.x.

Comment: Yes I was using Jdk 1.6. Updating to jdk 1.8 helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed and targeting *at least* Android 6.0 Marshmellow and are using Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1.

See [React Native setup docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) for more information.