# Could not run my React-Native app in device/emulator and i'm facing below error

Tags: android, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/engineer/Documents/reactnative/AwesomeProject/android/app/build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all the steps? ([Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html))

Check that the android and java home variables are well configured. Look at this question that is similar to yours. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42877685/5364022)

Comment: Thanks !! Yes, I have followed the installation  ( [Getting Started] (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) ) . Can you suggest me what should be process for it. As per react-native requirement we need three things ( JDK, Node.js, React-native ). So, Please suggest me what should be sequence. According to me Firstly JDK, Secondly Node.js and last React-Native. am i right? And one more think, Can you give me a link in which whole process is followed from start to end (JDK - React-Native).

Comment: I followed the getting started and it works. The sequence I think is right. Have you installed android sdk?

Comment: Good, It's a pleasure to have helped